# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash while incrementing an Int

Tags: ios, swift

I have a lot of crashes reports in my XCode Organizer.
Here is the trace

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000746a8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Breadcrumb Trail: (reverse chronological seconds)
9      GC Framework: startAuthenticationForExistingPrimaryPlayer


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                       0x00000001000746a8 DataManager.incrementKeywordIndexByTwo() -> () + 284 (DataManager.swift:106)
1   MyApp                       0x000000010007995c @objc ViewController.unwindToMainMenu(UIStoryboardSegue) -> () + 68 (ViewController.swift:50)
2   UIKit                           0x00000001874ac16c -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 216 (UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate.m:471)
3   UIKit                           0x00000001874ac05c -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 92 (UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate.m:458)
4   UIKit                           0x00000001872fe184 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 160 (UIStoryboardSegueTemplate.m:123)
5   UIKit                           0x0000000186becbe8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100 (UIApplication.m:4265)
6   UIKit                           0x0000000186becb64 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80 (UIControl.m:612)
7   UIKit                           0x0000000186bd4870 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 436 (UIControl.m:694)
8   UIKit                           0x0000000186bec454 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572 (UIControl.m:446)
9   MyApp                       0x0000000100081fe0 specialized GameButton.touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, withEvent : UIEvent?) -> () + 188 (GameButton.swift:85)
10  MyApp                       0x000000010008183c @objc GameButton.touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, withEvent : UIEvent?) -> () + 128 (GameButton.swift:0)
11  UIKit                           0x0000000186bec084 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 804 (UIWindow.m:2135)
12  UIKit                           0x0000000186be4c20 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 784 (UIWindow.m:2257)
13  UIKit                           0x0000000186bb504c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248 (UIApplication.m:12647)
14  UIKit                           0x0000000186bb3628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6568 (UIApplication.m:10454)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a0d09c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1761)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a0cb30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540 (CFRunLoop.c:1807)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a0a830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724 (CFRunLoop.c:2536)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181934c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
19  GraphicsServices                0x000000018321c088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
20  UIKit                           0x0000000186c1e088 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3772)
21  MyApp                       0x0000000100083920 main + 152 (AppDelegate.swift:14)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001814d28b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:78)
```

And here is the DataManager code (line 106)

```
var keywords = [Keyword]()
var keywordIndex = 0
func incrementKeywordIndexByTwo() {
    keywordIndex = (keywordIndex + 2) % keywords.count
}
```

I don't understand what is the cause of the crash, line 106 is just an addition with a modulo. 
KeywordIndex and keywords.count are both Int. 
And I can't reproduce the crash in my iPad mini 2 or in simulator.

Thanks

Comment: You're dividing by zero when `keywords` is empty

Comment: When this method is called keywords isn't empty

Comment: "When this method is called keywords isn't empty" So you assume. But we programmers have a saying: _don't_ assume. Your code does not check this assumption; it does not defend against the possibility that `keywords.count` is zero. Therefore, by Murphy's law, it will somehow be zero.

Comment: That's right :) After more reflexion I searched why keywords is empty at this time. And guess what? I found out !

Comment: @guillaume Here's a further bit of advice. Any time you make an assumption like this, put a `precondition`. That's what it's for! A `precondition` is a _bet_ against the program. If you lose the bet, you will crash, but you'll get a clear message telling you what went wrong — because you put the message there in the first place. `precondition(keywords.count != 0, "keywords should not be empty")`

Comment: Thank you. Indeed precondition will be usefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `keywords.count` is zero, you are performing a division by zero in effect, which causes an exception.

You need to either check that the `keywords` array has at least one member or perform a modulo 1 if `count` is zero.

Comment: Normally when this code is reached keywords can't be empty... I'm looking to check if something happens in my code en clear keywords

Comment: It is good practice to perform such a check nethertheless and/or to raise an exception / error. Also a great candidate for some tests.